# Merge large amount of files including only part of filename

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, vbscript, scripting

I'm having some trouble merging files that are generated through machinemonitoring-software. The software generates files that show what state a certain machine is on a given time, like shown below:

Format: `Time;Machine;Status`

```
23:40:52;KP66;ms:4
23:39:54;KP86;ms:4
23:49:24;KP86;ms:9999
23:38:17;Wasmachine1;ms:4
23:43:36;Wasmachine1;ms:9999
23:41:29;Meten1;ms:4
```

Every 15 minutes, a new file is generated with this data. The filename of each file shows the date + the time it was generated, like this `29-02-2016-23-50.sdat` (With .sdat being the extension, it can be opened with notepad).

To be able to properly input these files into visualisation-software and visualize it, i need the date and the time a certain status was logged for a certain machine. The date is included in the filename, and the time within the files itself.

I've created two seperate scripts to be able to 1. merge all the files into one textfile and 2. delete the .sdat extension, so the data is presented like this:

```
29-02-2016-05-20 5:05:37;KP85;ms:3
29-02-2016-05-20 5:05:39;KP85;ms:9999
29-02-2016-05-20 5:06:04;KP85;ms:3
29-02-2016-05-20 5:07:51;KP86;ms:4
29-02-2016-05-20 5:17:58;KP86;ms:9999
29-02-2016-05-20 5:19:13;KP86;ms:4
```

The problem is, because the "-05-20" part (after the date) is still there, it can't be recognized as a date and therefore i can't create a datetime field in the vis. software. The "05-20" changes with each file. I need some sort of script that can make my data look like this:

```
    29-02-2016 5:05:37;KP85;ms:3
    29-02-2016 5:05:39;KP85;ms:9999
    29-02-2016 5:06:04;KP85;ms:3
    29-02-2016 5:07:51;KP86;ms:4
```

These are the scripts i've used thus far. A batch file to merge all files including the full filename at the beginning of each line:

```
  @echo off
    (for %%f in (*.sdat) do (
      for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in (%%f) do @echo %%f %%a
    ))>Machinelogs.txt
```

And a vbs script to remove the ".sdat" part on each line:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const FileIn = "Machinelogs.txt"
Const FileOut = "Machinelogs.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileIn, ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, ".sdat", "")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileOut, ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

I've used another batchfile to call both scripts sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, something as simple as this should do all you want:

```dos
@(For /F "Tokens=1-5* Delims=-:" %%A In ('FindStr/R "^" *.sdat'
) Do @Echo(%%A-%%B-%%C %%F)>Machinelogs.txt
```

Comment: You've understood correctly, it works. Thanks and pardon my inability to script properly :p.